# Space in path name causing "Warning: invalid package" on install. R

Tags: r, windows, directory, package, installation

When running R-3.4.4 (on Windows 7, RStudio):

```
install.packages("ggplot2", destdir = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library/temp")
```

I get the following warning (presumably from the space in the path):

```
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3204655 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

Warning: invalid package 'C:/Program'
Warning: invalid package 'Files/R/R-3.4.4/library/temp/ggplot2_3.2.1.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.4\library" C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library/temp/ggplot2_3.2.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Although, trying to circumvent it using:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", destdir = "C:/Temp")
```

leads to:

```
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'pillar'
```

where

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library"
```

Again, trying to solve that warning with:

```
install.packages("pillar", destdir = "C:/Temp")
```

leads to

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Mary': No such file or directory
```

The full path is C:\Users\Mary Surname\etc\etc... Which brings it back to the first problem where there is a space between "FirstName" and "Surname" in the path.

Any way to correct the incorrect interpretation of the space. Note, the download is fine but it falls over trying to find the zip file it had only just downloaded.

Comment: While not the exact solution, I find that if you install R version >=3.5 a lot of these issues go away (e.g. you can install the RStudio packages from cran directly without issue).

Comment: Unfortunately had same issue with version 3.6.1 even when installing directly (Tools→Install packages).